# Twig: use random image from folder

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony with Twig. I would like to display a random image from a folder in `web/`. The number of images in my folder is not constant; it can be zero, one, or hundreds.

I know Twig has a random() function, but as far as I can tell this only works if I know how many files are in my folder. Is there any other built-in function that I could use to pick a random image?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well, you have the following architecture:
web > multiple folders > multiples images.

To be able to access the folder, you must have access to its name. So, you want to get randomly an image from that folder.

I will suggest you to get your image from your controller, as it contains some logics that have nothing to do in a twig: search in your folder...) and send it to the twig.

If your images are associated to an entity Image, which is linked to the entity used in your page, just doing a leftjoin in your request in your controller with a random offset will do the job. You can find some previous questions on stackoverflow about random request.

If your image is not associated with any entity, you need to know what is in your file. You might want to use one of these 2 links:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html